# SAS proc SQL and arrays

Tags: sas

This is a newbie SAS question. I have a dataset with numerical variables `v1-v120`, `V` and a categorical variable `Z`(with say three possible values). For each possible value of `Z`, I would like to get another set of variables `w1-w120`, where `w{i}=sum(v{i}}/V`, where the sum is a sum over a given value of `Z`. Thus I am looking for 3*120 matrix in this case. I can do this in data step, but would like to do it by `Proc SQL` or `Proc MEANS`, as the number of categorical variables in the actual dataset is moderately large. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using proc sql.  You could probably also do something similar with proc means using an output dataset and a 'by' statement.

```
data t1;
    input z v1 v2 v3;
    datalines;
        1 2 3 4
        2 3 4 5
        3 4 5 6
        1 7 8 9
        2 4 7 9
        3 2 2 2
    ;
run;

%macro listForSQL(varstem1, varstem2, numvars);
    %local numWithCommas;
    %let numWithCommas = %eval(&numvars - 1);
    %local i;
    %do i = 1 %to &numWithCommas;
        mean(&varstem1.&i) as &varstem2.&i,
    %end;
    mean(&varstem1.&numvars) as &varstem2.&numvars
%mend listForSQL;

proc sql;
    create table t2 as
        select
            z,
            %listForSQL(v, z, 3)
        from t1
        group by z
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you ..I thought we need to use Macro for this

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do this with `proc means`. Using the `t1` data set from Louisa Grey's answer:

```
proc means data=t1 nway noprint;
  class z;
  var v1-v3;
  output out=t3 mean=w1-w3;
run;
```

This creates an table of results that match the SQL results.

Comment: Proc means will work.. but if you need to create a new variable (within the proc statement) using  two existing variables then proc means fails

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- are you using two variables in the question example? You can always you a data view to generate variables without actually using I/O resources.