# Multiplying multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SAS proc SQL and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381103/sas-proc-sql-and-arrays)

I am trying to calculate the ratios of multiple columns, multiple times in SAS using SQL. For example, I want:

```
(((start*start_period)+(middle*middle_period)+(end*end_period))/number_days) AS azmonth;
```

The problem is that while `start_period`, `middle_period`, `end_period`, and `number_days` are constant and `start`, `middle`, and `end` are one set of about 7 sets that need to be multiplied in the same way.  Is there a way besides typing it out for each of them?

1. Start_per  Mid_per  End_per Start1....Start20 Mid1...Mid20  End1...End20
2. .3--------------.6----------.1------10-------15------26-------45-----61------08

I know I can do a seperate equation for each of the Start, Mid, and Ends but i was hoping there was a way I could do it without having to copy/paste edit al of them individually?

Comment: are you saying that the constant values could be set prior to your PROC SQL statement? or are they contained in your data set? input data would be helpful

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Be sure to register.  I edited your question to describe what you're using up front, and I used code formatting to clarify your code, so that it is easier for someone who hasn't see it before to understand. I hope our community can help!

Comment: They could be set prior to Proc SQL or could be added to the dataset, whichever might be easier to accomplish.

Comment: ok, provide some sample data. What would your input data set look like? What would start_period, middle_period, etc look like?

Comment: @CarolinaJay65 I put in a line of sample data above, I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Still really unclear. What is `Start1` supposed to multiply? What do you want the result for this line of input to be?

Comment: Could you please post the exact CREATE TABLE statement that makes your table?  I think you might be able to do this by programatically creating a string that looks like an SQL UPDATE statement (using a while loop) then EXEC ing that string.  I'm not usually a fan of that but it might be the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

Write a macro before you run PROC SQL to generate the repetitive code for you, then call the macro at the appropriate point within proc SQL. If you were doing this in a data step instead, an alternative option would be to define 3 arrays for the start, middle and end variables and then repeat the calculation 20 times using a do loop.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381103/sas-proc-sql-and-arrays).

[This source](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Arrays_and_Proc_SQL_Question) claims that there is no looping capability within PROC SQL itself - I'm not sure whether this is true or not. If it is, a macro may be the only solution.